# xlwings.XlwingsError: Couldn't find your SharePoint file locally, see xlwings.org/error

Tags: python, xlwings

I am trying to run the Python code and access ms-excel (.xlsm) file using xlwings module (latest version), but I am always getting the error :
"xlwings.XlwingsError: Couldn't find your SharePoint file locally, see xlwings.org/error"

Is there any **setting** that we need to do to make this thing work on our system with OneDrive (Commercial) enabled. All the files are synced with Green tick.

Do we need to add any specific environment variable (PATH) to make xlwings work along with OneDrive?

I also looked on the xlwings documentations ::

**xlwings only works with OneDrive and SharePoint files that are synced to a local folder! This means that both, the Excel and Python file, need to show the green check mark in the File Explorer/Finder as status**

[image: Error]

Comment: Please have a look at the docs and let me know where the documentation needs to improve: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/onedrive_sharepoint.html#onedrive-sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when I installed xlwings on my colleagues machine. This was version 0.26.2. I uninstalled it and ran pip install xlwings==0.23.3 as this was the version I use. This allowed the script to access workbooks saved on Sharepoint.